# Instagram - Get post comments

Tags: instagram

I did create a client in Instagram API but I'm in sandbox mode. My wife have a makeup store account and she is doing a giveaway and the rules is comment a post and mention another 3 friends. So, how can I get all the comments of the photo using or not Instagram API?

We have a web application in: www.beautyglamsd.com and I though that I can put the people that already are in the comments.

Answer (score 1):

You can use service [like this one](https://lizaonair.com/giveaway/) to host your giveaway (works for Instagram, Youtube, Tiktok and VK). You can automate all tasks and save your time (check for like, follow, sponsors).